# Pandas Group-By and Sum not creating a new Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe -

```
     TransactionDT  TransactionAmt  TransactionHour
   0    86400          68.5                 0
   1    86401          29.0                 1
   2    86469          59.0                 1
   3    86499          50.0                 2
   4    86506          50.0                 3
```

I want to create a new data frame that sums `TransactionAmt` grouping by `TransactionHour`, like -

```
        Sum(TransactionAmt) TransactionHour
     0         68.5                 0
     1         88.0                 1        (sum of those with TransactionHour == 1)      
     2         50.0                 2
     3         50.0                 3
```

The code I wrote was -

```
sliced_data2 = data.groupby(['TransactionHour'])['TransactionAmt'].sum()
```

But it only gives me the `Sum(TransactionHour)`

Comment: When you say "create a new dataframe ... grouping by TransactionHour", you really mean "I want to see TransactionHour in the output, as the index". This is the non-default setting [`pd.DataFrame.groupby(..., as_index=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) : *"`as_index=False` is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output"*

Comment: Please mark any of the answers as Accepted if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Please close this is a duplicate. There are [**249 questions with "groupby as_index False"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=groupby+as_index+False+votes%3A2). Which is the best dupe target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sliced_data2 = data.groupby(['TransactionHour'])['TransactionAmt'].agg('sum')`

This will work

Answer (score 1):

```
sliced_data2 = data.groupby('TransactionHour',as_index = False).agg({"TransactionAmt" : "sum"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
raw_data = {'TransactionDT':      [86400, 86401, 86469, 86499, 86506],
            'TransactionAmt':     [68.5, 29.0, 59.0, 50.0, 50.0],
            'TransactionHour':    [0,1,1,2,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

df.groupby('TransactionHour',as_index = False).agg({"TransactionAmt" : "sum"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as_index=False` to make sure you are not setting the column that's being grouped as the new index for the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'TransactionDT':[86400, 86401, 86469, 86499, 86506],'TransactionAmt':[68.5, 29.0, 59.0, 50.0, 50.0],'TransactionHour':[0,1,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
sliced_df = df.groupby(['TransactionHour'],as_index=False)['TransactionAmt'].sum())
print(sliced_df)
```

Output:

```
   TransactionHour  TransactionAmt
0                0            68.5
1                1            88.0
2                2            50.0
3                3            50.0
```